# Is it safe to remove files in Nexus tmp folder?

Tags: maven, nexus, diskspace

While trying to clear up some disk space, I noticed that many Gigabytes of data lie around in the 'sonatype-work/nexus/tmp' folder. The biggest directory is called 'nexus-maven-repository-index.gz*.dir' and I am hesitating to remove it. Is that just a temporary and unused copy of the repository index which I can safely delete?

The documentation of the [Nexus Directories](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-dirs.html) does not provide sufficient information about the 'tmp' folder. It only says that it is the "Folder used for temporary storage".

Comment: have you configured task to cleanup time line and the trash?

Comment: Yes, but those tasks do not seem to clean up the tmp folder.

Comment: ah...Misunderstanding on my site. I would just simply delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be safe to delete this content. Please note that treatment of the tmp folder recently changed in the 2.8.1 release.

Also going forward you should use the Empty Trash scheduled task. See http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/09/nexus-scheduled-tasks/

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more in detail what has change in which way?

Comment: It should not affect you but fyi https://docs.sonatype.com/display/SPRTNXOSS/Sonatype+Nexus+Release+Notes#SonatypeNexusReleaseNotes-TemporaryDirectoryHandledConsistently

Comment: I removed the file from the `tmp` folder... Nexus is still up and running :)

Comment: 'Empty Trash' freed up so much space, cannot clean up space without it it seems.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying but yes... you should use Empty Trash and the scheduled tasks for it since it cleans up more than just the tmp folder..